# TYPO3 Neos 1.2.3 Server communication error: Internal Server Error

Tags: neoscms

I have installed TYPO3 Neos 1.2.3.  When I am trying to edit content in neos backend, I got different different type of errors. Please have a look at below screenshots.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any one can help me, very appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Dear down voter!! Thanks for you show your frustration on my question. But really, If I faced that issue and if I posted my question with screenshot of error, then definitely my question is not fake. Your down vote doesn't help me anymore. Please ask your self, your are really expert or master in Neos? If yes, try to help me, If no, go ahead man go... "inspiring people to share! Never forget that, my friends!" by - kasper http://typo3.org/about/kaspers-korner/ Please read this article carefully. Hope, might be you can understand meaning of "HELP"

Comment: I've have same problem, Even i update to 2.1 it happens again. Actually this is conflict in broken nodes. If you will publish all changes every time the problem not happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is Sebastian Kurfürst of the Neos team. Could you please check the logs in `Data/Logs/System_Development.log`? They contain full-detail stack traces and it helps us to trace down the issue.

Additionally, we have had some nasty regressions in Neos 1.2.3. Could you please try to update to Neos 1.2.6 and see if the error prevails?

Looking forward to help out on this issue, Thanks a lot,
Sebastian

Comment: #Sebastian, thank you for you here for help. I seen log files. There are some repeated logs "Router route(): A cached Route with the cache identifier", "No CSRF required", "FrontendNodeRoutePartHandler matchValue()", "Uncaught exception #1336662898" How can I solve that one?

Comment: Also, let me try your suggestion Neos 1.2.3 update to Neos 1.2.6. One question: Is it server issue? coz in my local ubuntu PC it's working fine, when I upload on live I got that issue. Neos BE handle many Ajax request, might be that one issue?

Comment: Hi Sebastian! Great to see other TYPO3 community members on StackOverflow. However, this post was flagged as low-quality because it does not really answer the question. Asking for feedback should preferably be done in the comments section.

Comment: Hallo #helmbert, Sebastian is just trying to help me, that doesn't mater in which section should be answer or comment and quality of question. coz someone seen my question but no one try to answer or comment.

Comment: Yeah, I did not have enough reputation to comment on posts yet. That's why I needed to respond...